# saving the numpy image datasets. without increase in size and easy to save and load data

Tags: python, numpy

i have saved my train test val array into pickle file. but the size of images is 1.5GB ,pickle file is 16GB i.e size increased. is another any another way to save those numpy images array without increase in size?

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.save` function ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)) or `numpy.savez_compresion` function ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)).

Read documentation before ask question.

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np 


image = np.random.randint(0, 200, (199818,50,50,3), dtype=np.uint8)
image2 = np.random.randint(0, 200, (1998,50,50,3), dtype=np.uint8)

np.savez_compressed("test.npz", image, img=image2)

img_dkt = np.load("test.npz")

print("First_array:", img_dkt["arr_0"].shape, "equality", np.all(image == img_dkt["arr_0"]))
print("second_array:", img_dkt["img"].shape, "equality", np.all(image2 == img_dkt["img"]))
```

Comment: i  have used numpy.savez_compresion  . but the shape after loading changed. (199818,50,50,3) changed to a tuple. how to save without change in shape

Comment: I do not understand. (199818,50,50,3) is a tuple.

Comment: i have saved an ndarray of size (199818,50,50,3)  and after loading it , it returns a tuple and size is changed to (484,550) ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I updated answer with working code sample.